# Should it be waitress or waittressing?

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns

My Sentence: "Jobs such as waitress, janitor, fast food workers and much more low-level jobs are consider unchallenging for the uneducated. "

Comment: The way you have it at the moment is not grammatical. You could either say *jobs such as that of waitress, janitor...etc*, or you could say *Jobs such as waitressing, janitoring,...etc*. You may find that some people nowadays object to the word *waitress* on the grounds that it is gender stereotyping.

Comment: You have other grammatical errors as well: "much more jobs" and "are consider".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it should be waitressing, because a waitress is a person, whereas waitressing is a job.  A waitress's job is waitressing.  Your sentence, rendered correctly, would be:

> Jobs such as waitressing, janitorial work, fast food service, and many more low-level jobs are considered unchallenging for the uneducated.

All of the nouns you mentioned -- waitress, janitor, fast food worker -- were people rather than jobs.

Also, it's a little awkward to end a list that began with a "such as" clause with a "many more" clause.  In my opinion, this would be better:

> Low-level jobs such as waitressing, janitorial work, and fast foot service are considered unchallenging for the uneducated.